For a Next.js application, how can I dynamically inject global content on the server-side without affecting static page caching?
I'm working on a Next.js application where I need to inject some global content (e.g., configuration data, user-specific information) on the server-side for each request. However, I want to maintain the benefits of static page caching for performance reasons.
Is there a way to achieve this server-side injection without invalidating the static cache for my pages? I'm looking for a solution that allows me to:

Inject dynamic content for each request
Keep the static nature of my pages intact
Avoid using client-side rendering for this global content

Any suggestions or best practices for handling this scenario in Next.js would be greatly appreciated.
Here are some approaches I've already tried:

Using getInitialProps in _app.tsx:
I attempted to use getInitialProps to fetch dynamic data on each request, but this disabled automatic static optimization for all pages.
Server-side props with getServerSideProps and getStaticProps:
I tried using a combination of getStaticProps for static content and getServerSideProps for dynamic data in individual pages. While this approach can work, it requires implementing the same logic in every page file, which is not ideal for maintaining global dynamic content across the entire application.

